# jQuery setInterval / hovering : it works once, but then stops the setInterval

Tags: jquery, hover, setinterval

i have a problem with my 'setInterval' function, i'd like to start the function when i'm hovering my div, but the setInterval work just at the first time when i hover the div => if i'm staying on the div, it doesn't keep on changing the picture, but stop the 'setinterval'.

Is it a problem with mouseenter? i tried 'hover', etc. but nothing seems to make the trick.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot for your help, here's my code :

```
img.bind('mouseenter', function(){
    setInterval(next($(this)),1000);
});

function next(elem){  
    var img_li = elem.find('li');  
    count++;  
    if (count>2) count=0;  

    img_li.eq(count).fadeIn('fast', function(){  
        img_li.eq(current).css({'display':'none'});

        current = count;  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are assigning the return value of next($(this)) to the setInterval and not the function itself.

Try this:

```
img.bind('mouseenter', function(){     
    var that = $(this); //Use that-this model to avoid any scope issues with this reference
    setInterval(function(){
        next(that);
    },1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [jQuery Timers](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/) plugin, which makes it easier to work with such functions. In particular, have a look at the following:

> everyTime(interval : Integer | String, [label = interval : String], fn : Function, [times = 0 : Integer])
>
> everyTime will add the defined function (fn) as a timed event to run at a given time interval (interval) for a given number of times (times). If times is set to 0, the number of times the method is called is unbounded. A label is also set for the given timed event either to the provided string (label) or to the string representation of the interval provided. Additionally, the interval can be defined by using a string such as "3s" for 3 seconds.